# Is Wiley Plus able to detect when students are cheating?

Tags: cheating, online-learning

I am supposed to start teaching on Wiley Plus for the first time this coming summer semester, and as someone who is already not the most tech-savvy, I have concerns regarding students cheating on homework assignments. Is there a way for me to do detect if students are copying questions or pasting answers from online? I am told Wiley creates unique variables per every question but keeps the same question. This would mean someone can go on "Chegg," or "Slader," to obtain a method to answer a question, without attempting it themselves.

Would Wiley contact me if they find a question posted by one of my students on Chegg? Since each question is unique to each student? I want to figure all these things out before I start setting up the course.

Answer (score 4):

Neither Wiley nor any other system will do this for you.  You could do a web search with the specific text of your questions, and solutions on an online source will show up (or at least their existence will show up), but you will have to do this yourself.

Besides, let's say you find out that some question appeared.  What would you do?  Wiley creates several versions of each question with different numbers, but with tens of thousands of students, there will still be hundreds of students at universities all across the world getting the same question, so you really cannot tell it is any of your students.  In fact, even if a question has 30 versions, it is likely that every single one of those 30 versions is already on Chegg.  And if the system generates a 31th version, that will show up on Chegg in a matter of hours after some student somewhere in the world gets it.